# Running a standalone exe made from python 3.5 in windows xp

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, windows-xp, cx-freeze

We created a python program with tensorflow in python 3.5. Based on our research python 3.5 and tensorflow are not supported in xp. But if we converted it to an exe file using cx_freeze, will it work?

Comment: The situation won't be any different if you use cx_freeze. There's still the same Python interpreter (just without the interactive shell), and the same libraries (packaged more conveniently), and your scripts (in the form of .pyc files, i.e. Python bytecode). The .exe file you see there just initializes the interpreter (which resides in a dll) and commands it to execute your script.

Answer (score 0):

The situation won't be any different if you use cx_freeze. There's still the same Python interpreter (just without the interactive shell), and the same libraries (packaged more conveniently), and your scripts (in the form of .pyc files, i.e. Python bytecode). The .exe file you see there just initializes the interpreter (which resides in a dll) and commands it to execute your script.